# Boost ASIO shared library trouble

Tags: multithreading, gcc, boost, boost-asio, shared

I'm basically building a shared library based on the serialisation example in the ASIO documentation, by this I mean I am compiling with the -shared and -fpic options to produce an .so file, which includes hooks/wrappers.

I'm running my shared library against another process and then my code gets run through the constructor function within the library (like DLLMain on Windows).

I know my code is being executed and it runs fine up until a certain point. Basically my problem involves trying to put ASIO and my networking code onto another thread. I'm using the following code to do that:

```
asio::io_service io_service;
server server(io_service, port);
asio::thread t(boost::bind(&asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
```

Now, as this code is run within a constructor function within the library, is throws a seg fault and I can't figure out why. If I replace it with:

```
asio::io_service io_service;
server server(io_service, port);
io_service.run();
```

The code runs 100% fine, except it steals the whole thread of execution and the hooked process won't run at all. Can anyone help me out here? I'm really confused.

Cheers

Comment: I suspect, its something related to object lifetime. Are you using t.join() after asio::thread statement?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a lifetime issue.

If the following code is in a function within the library:

```
void some_function()
{
  asio::io_service io_service;
  server server(io_service, port);
  asio::thread t(boost::bind(&asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
}
```

Then whenever the function returns, `io_service` will go out of scope, being destroyed while the newly spawned thread is trying to process the event loop.  Consider changing it so that the lifetime of `io_service` and `server` extends to at least the duration of the thread:

```
void server_run()
{
  asio::io_service io_service;
  server server(io_service, port);
  io_service.run();
}

...

asio::thread t(&server_run);
```